Estoy programando un método en mi clase controladora el cual me debe devolver un Array que contenga a los trabajadores con más años de experiencia
El error que hay en mi código y no encuentro es que me devuelve a todos los trabajadores directivos , no a el o los que tienes más años de experiencia
public ArrayList<Trabajadores> mayorExperiencia(){
     ArrayList<Trabajadores>trabajadoresEncontrados=new ArrayList<>();
   
    for(Trabajadores trab:trabajadores){
        int mayorExp=0;
        if(trab instanceof TrabajadorDirectivo){
             
            if(((TrabajadorDirectivo) trab).getAnnosExperiencia()>=mayorExp){
                mayorExp=((TrabajadorDirectivo) trab).getAnnosExperiencia();
                
            }trabajadoresEncontrados.add(trab);
        }
    }return trabajadoresEncontrados;
 }


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! trabajadoresEncontrados.add(trab); con eso, agregas a todos.. es mas.. pudiste agregar a gente que no tenia el maximo que controlaste antes...  deberias recorrer la lista dos veces, una para fijarte el maximo, otra para comprobar quienes tienen ese maximo...

La línea trabajadoresEncontrados.add(trab); se ejecuta siempre.

Debes colocar el add() sólo cuando encuentres algún trabajador con más años de experiencia:
if(((TrabajadorDirectivo) trab).getAnnosExperiencia()>=mayorExp){
    mayorExp=((TrabajadorDirectivo) trab).getAnnosExperiencia();
   trabajadoresEncontrados.add(trab);
}

Además deberias limpiar de trabjadoresEncontrados los trabajadores con menos años que el nuevo valor de mayorExp.

Gracias , me podrías dar una idea de cómo hacer eso último que me dices

Te dejo unas pequeñas correcciones a tu código, para que este sea funcional.
public ArrayList<Trabajadores> mayorExperiencia() {
   List<Trabajadores> encontrados = new ArrayList<>();
   int mayorExp = 0;
   for( Trabajadores trab : trabajadores ) {
      if( trab instanceof Directivo ) {             
         if( ((Directivo) trab).getAnnosExperiencia() >= mayorExp ) {
              // si el directivo actual tiene mas experiencia que la especificada
              // en "mayorExp", puede decir que es el primer directivo que tiene más que
              // "0" años de experiencia, en cuyo caso instanciamos "encontrados", 
              // que el nuevo, tiene más que los ya encontrados, en ese caso, eliminamos 
              // los anteriores... instanciando "encontrados"
            encontrados = new ArrayList<>();
            mayorExp = ((Directivo) trab).getAnnosExperiencia();
              // y lo agregamos a la nueva lista
            encontrados.add( trab );
         }
         else if( ((Directivo) trab).getAnnosExperiencia() == mayorExp ) {
              // en caso de tener la misma experiencia ue los contenidos en "encontrados", lo agregamos
            encontrados.add( trab );
         }
      }
   }
    return encontrados;
}

Como verás, me tomé el terrible atrevimiento de modificar algunos nombres de variables, en parte porque hacen más corto el ejemplo, y también porque me parecen que lo hacen más legible.

Hola , amigo lo hice cómo me indica pero me devuelve siempre el último trabajador directivo del array sin importar que no sea el que tenga más años de experiencia .

Mil perdones @RafaelCruzJorge, el int mayorExp = 0; va antes de iniciar el for, fijate que edite la respuesta. también instancie debidamente encontrados.
